# Attempting to create a python library for the first time. Getting plagued with modulenotfounderror

Tags: python, import, module, package

Creating a simple client library so that someone who uses my api will have an easy time of it. Fairly new to python (3 months) and never created my own module/library/package before. I watched a ton of very simple tutorials and thought I was doing it properly. But I'm getting a module not found error despite following the instructions to the letter. Here is the basic format (**Note, I've replaced the names of most files, classes, and methods because of a workplace policy, it should have no impact on the structure however**)

```
python-sdk (the name of the repository)
 |    ⊢src (my boss wants everything wrapped inside of a src directory)
 |    |    ⊢library (this will be the package that is imported by users)
 |    |    |    ⊢__init__.py
 |    |    |    ⊢filename.py
 |    |    |    |    ⊢class myclass1
 |    |    |    |    |    ⊢staticmethod()
 |    |    |    |    ⊢class myclass2
 |    |    |    |    |    ⊢method()
 |    |    test-app.py
```

currently filename contains 2 classes (very simple classes just for the sake of testing) named myclass1 and myclass2. Each class contains a single method that for right now just adds or multiplies 2 values. I'm just doing this for learning creating libraries. I know how the code will be implemented later.

the init file contains the following:

```
from filename import myclass1, myclass2
```

the test app is simply:

```
from library import myclass1, myclass2
print(myclass1.staticmethod1(15, 20))

myclassinstance = myclass2(15, 20)

print(myclassinstance.method())
```

According to the stack trace, it begins at line one of test-app.py it sees the import of library so it goes to the init file inside library. Then at line 1 of init, it sees the from filename import myclass1, myclass2 and gets mad at filename.

it says:

```
/home/sexmaster/PycharmProjects/python-sdk/venv/bin/python /home/sexmaster/PycharmProjects/python-sdk/src/test-app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sexmaster/PycharmProjects/python-sdk/src/test-app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from library import myclass1, myclass2
  File "/home/derek1st/PycharmProjects/python-sdk/src/library/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from filename import class1, class2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'filename'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any guesses? This should be pretty darn basic. I can't figure out what is wrong. I got no red lines in pycharm for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you're trying to do a relative import from the __init__file you should add a period before filename like this.

```
from .filename import myclass1, myclass2
```

then you can import from the package:

```
from library import myclass1, myclass2
```

**here's the explanaition as requested:**

When we are working with related modules inside a package it its kind of redundant to specify the full path because we know what our parent module is named so a relative import is basically a way of saying find a class, function or module as it is positioned relative to the current module.

suppose we have the following package:

```
parent_directory/
      main.py
      ecommerce/
          __init__.py
          database.py
          products.py
          payments/
              __init__.py
              paypal.py
              stripe.py
```

if we are working in the *products* module and we want to import  the *Database* class from the *database* module next to it  we use a relative import:

```
from .database import Database
```

The period in front of database says: *use the database module inside the current package.*

if we were editing the *paypal* module inside the ecommerce/payments package and we want to use the *database* module inside the parent package *(ecommerce package)* this would be done as follows:

```
from ..database import Database
```

we can use more periods to go further up in the hierarchy and also we can go down one side and back up another (leave it as exercise for the reader)

Now, remember that the `__init__.py` file defines a directory as a package and it can contain any variable or class declarations and they will be available as part of the package so in our example if the `ecommerce/__init__.py` file contained this line:

```
from .database import db
```

we could then acces the db attribute from main.py or any other file using the next import:

```
from ecommerce import db
```

I personally recommend not putting to much code in the `__init__` file because python developers do not actually expect logic to happen in it.

in your particular case, your `__init__.py` file is relative to the filename module, that's why it is needed to do a relative import. Nevertheless, you could also do an absolute import directly in your test-app.py as follows:

```
from library.filename import myclass1, myclass2
```

both import methods are correct, use the one that makes your code look more elegant

for further reading:

- D. Phillips, Python 3 Object-Oriented Programming 3ed

Comment: First of all, that worked, so thank you so much. But more importantly, can you follow-up a little bit about WHY that worked. The tutorial I was following didn't include a period. By "relative import" I assume you mean because it was importing from a location inside my project rather than from an external library or something. The tutorials all were "relative" imports too without the period. I thought the period in linux only hid a file. What is the significance?

Comment: there is the explanaition already, glad it helped